# Jbuilder pass in single object to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I have a partial that I'm using for collections

```
json.(message, :topic, :body, :id, :created_at)
```

I can pass in collections to it like so

```
json.partial! partial: 'users/messages', collection: @conversation, as: :message
```

What's the syntax for passing in a single instance (`@message`)? I've tried to `locals` option and also

```
json.partial! 'users/messages', @message, as: :message
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
json.partial! 'users/messages', locals: { message: @message }
```

This line similar to example from official [README](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Comment: I've tried with the `locals` option but still get `undefined local variable or method 'message'`

Comment: This is very strange. Probably you are call this partial from several places and one place don't pass `message` variable?